# Reducer Dispatch Push Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Could someone look at my reducer to see what the issue is with `.push()`? For some reason the following error is being thrown

> error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

but the value isn't undefined.

```
Cart Reducer State = {"cartItems":[],"itemCount":0,"total":0}
Cart Reducer Action = {"type":"ADD_ITEM","payload":{"_id":"61cb88d85f499fd4563e99d3","sku":1001,"image":"blueband","title":"Wrist Band - 1 Custom Insert","description":"Band with custom photo insert included with purchase.","active":{"status":true,"display":true,"startDate":"2021-09-21T22:55:03.686Z","endDate":""},"color":"Blue","quantity":100,"price":16.99,"createdAt":"2021-12-28T21:59:52.357Z","updatedAt":"2021-12-28T21:59:52.357Z","__v":0}}
```

```
export const sumItems = (cartItems) => {
  return {
    itemCount: cartItems.reduce((total, prod) => total + prod.quantity, 0),
    total: cartItems.reduce(
      (total, prod) => total + prod.price * prod.quantity,
      0
    ),
  };
};

const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_ITEM":
      //check if item is in cart
      if (!state.cartItems.find((item) => item._id === action.payload._id)) {
        //Below is an Object
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(action));
        state.cartItem.push({
          ...action.payload,
          quantity: 1,
        });
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems],
        ...sumItems(state.cartItems),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an initial state to your reducer.
You’re currently returning `state` in the `default` case, which will be `undefined` initially (Check in redux-dev tools).

In your reducer definition, set a default value to the state argument, Something like this `state = {cartItems: [], itemCount: 0, total: 0}`.

or you could move the initial state in a file say `state.js` with the following content:

```js
export default {
  cartItems: [],
  itemCount: 0,
  total: 0
}
```

and then import this in your reducer:

```
import initialState from './state';
```

and set the `initialState` in your reducer via default value of argument or just return `initalState` from the `default` case:

```
default: 
  return initialState;
```

Comment: Add it here? ```const cartReducer = (state = {}, action) => {```

Comment: Yes that should work. Or, assign it the actual initial state you want your application to have

Comment: Still throwing -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push').. When the reducer is called state is being passed in.

Comment: @AndrewVargas you have to assign initial state of your application from what I understand it should be state = {cartItems: []}

Comment: Spelling Error!!!!! state.cartItems.push()

Comment: haha, cool. Even if you fix the spelling, you'll need to fix the intial state part. I'm updating my answer

Comment: I have this where I defined the initialState. 

```
const initialState = { cartItems: [], itemCount: 0, total: 0 };

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState); 
```

Comment: @AndrewVargas You don't need to set initialState using useReducer. I've updated my answer with more details.